# In SQL How do I copy values from one table to another based on another field's value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Okay I have two tables

VOUCHERT with the following fields

```
ACTIVATIONCODE
SERIALNUMBER
VOUCHERDATADBID 
UNAVAILABLEAT   
UNAVAILABLEOPERATORDBID 
AVAILABLEAT 
AVAILABLEOPERATORDBID   
ACTIVATIONCODENEW   
EXT1    
EXT2    
EXT3    
DENOMINATION -- I added this column into the table.
```

and the second table is VOUCHERDATAT with the following fields

```
VOUCHERDATADBID
BATCHID
VALUE
CURRENCY
VOUCHERGROUP
EXPIRYDATE
AGENT
EXT1
EXT2
EXT3
```

What I want to do is copy the corresponding VALUE from VOUCHERDATAT and put it into DENOMINATION of VOUCHERT. The linking between the two is VOUCHERDATADBID. How do I go about it?

It is not a 1:1 mapping. What I mean is there may be 1000 SERIALNUMBERS with a same VOUCHERDATADBID. And that VOUCHERDATADBID has only entry in VOUCHERDATAT, hence one value. Therefore, all serial numbers belonging to a certain VOUCHERDATADBID will have the same value.

Will JOINS work? What type of JOIN should I use? Or is UPDATE table the way to go?

Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one of design. None of your tables are in any of the normal forms, not even in the first normal form (1NF). You should not add a column to the `VOUCHERT` table, but create a new table (pick the name) with the following columns: `SERIALNUMBER`, `VALUE`, `VOUCHERDATADBID` (maybe `ACTIVATIONCODE` too - need to know the primary key on `VOUCHERT` to be sure if `ACTIVATIONCODE` should be included in the new table). Normalization is the database design process that aims to resolve any possible `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` anomalies. This should solve your `INSERT` issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join between these two tables and you will get a 'view'. You can update this view like:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * 
        FROM VOUCHERT A JOIN VOUCHERDATAT B 
             ON A.VOUCHERDATADBID = B.VOUCHERDATADBID) 
SET DENOMINATION = VALUE;
```

You may put outer join if you need.

VOUCHERDATADBID MUST BE PRIMARY KEY in VOUCHERDATAT and FOREIGN KEY in VOUCHERT, otherwise you will get an error:

```
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

Comment: I've tried running your previous query, it timed out twice. First time I let it run for 6 hours, and 2nd time it ran for 3 hours. Will try this version and get back to you. Thanks !

Comment: so your problem is that the tables are too large !? how many rows do you have in each table ?

Comment: Vouchert has 264,582,461 rows and
voucherdatat has 994 rows.

I guess this is where the problem lies. Not enough RAM I guess

Comment: Well .. your question should be rephrased, to specify that you have lots of values :) because this requires a specialized solution. And maybe you would have to use PL/SQL to process in smaller batches. You said: 1000 SERIALNUMBERS with a same VOUCHERDATADBID, but if you have 250 milion to 1000, then it means 1 VOUCHERDATABID can have 250 000 SERIALNUMBERS :D

Comment: Yes yes, sorry my bad. I just gave those numbers as an example for a 1:N ratio. I'm working on a different approach. Will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
update  (
        select  v.DENOMINATION
        ,       vd.VALUE
        from    VOUCHERT v
        join    VOUCHERDATAT vd
        on      vd.VOUCHERDATADBID = v.VOUCHERDATADBID
        ) t
set     t.DENOMINATION = t.Value
```

Comment: shouldn't be join ... ON ? instead of WHERE ? If you use where then replace JOIN with a comma , and you will get the old style of joins.

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu: Yes, should be `on` instead of `where`, edited in answer.

Comment: I'm getting the following error. is "as t" valid? I've copied the code line by line. Thanks


ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Comment: @Joshua1729: Looks like Oracle doesn't allow `as` before the alias (looking [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/06/18/oracle-update-with-join-again.aspx) for syntax)

Answer (score 0):

If the voucherdatadbid is not a primary key, this should work:

```
UPDATE vouchert
   SET denomination =
       (SELECT MAX(value)
          FROM voucherdatat
         WHERE voucherdatadbid = vouchert.voucherdatadbid);
```

Comment: I think you mean "FROM voucherdatat" right? -- Thanks will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: And if you're updating 264 million rows, be prepared for it to take a while.